# How can I round off the corners of a CheckBox template in WPF Blend?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend, blend

So I created a CheckBox template in Visual Studio Blend and then wanted to round off the corners. However, there is only one border in the whole template that only rounds off the checkbox itself: [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgKAo.png)
but not the Background, i made the Background Colorized because I want to turn this CheckBox into a slide / toggle button.
it because it is a grid.

Template:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Background" Color="#FFFFFFFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Border" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <Style x:Key="OptionMarkFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="14,0,0,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Background" Color="#FFF3F9FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Border" Color="#FF5593FF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Border" Color="#FFBCBCBC"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph" Color="#FF707070"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFD9ECFF"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Border" Color="#FF3C77DD"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OptionMark.Static.Glyph" Color="#FF212121"/>
    <Style x:Key="CheckBoxStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Border}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
                    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="-0.729,-0.854,0.75,0">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="checkBoxBorder" CornerRadius="25" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0" Background="Red" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0.931,0.912,0,-0.092" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Height="52.784" Width="56.319" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                            <Grid x:Name="markGrid">
                                <Path x:Name="optionMark" Data="F1 M 9.97498,1.22334L 4.6983,9.09834L 4.52164,9.09834L 0,5.19331L 1.27664,3.52165L 4.255,6.08833L 8.33331,1.52588e-005L 9.97498,1.22334 Z " Fill="{StaticResource OptionMark.Static.Glyph}" Margin="1" Opacity="0" Stretch="None"/>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="indeterminateMark" Fill="#FF0C0C0C" Margin="2" Opacity="0" Stroke="{x:Null}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasContent" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource OptionMarkFocusVisual}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="4,-1,0,0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.MouseOver.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Disabled.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="checkBoxBorder" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Border}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="optionMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="{StaticResource OptionMark.Pressed.Glyph}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="optionMark" Value="0"/>
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="indeterminateMark" Value="1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <CheckBox Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="53" Margin="219,155,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185" Style="{DynamicResource CheckBoxStyle1}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Could you share your template?

Comment: i edit the Question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another `Border` around `Grid`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
        <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" Background="{x:Null}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="-0.729,-0.854,0.75,0">
        ....
        </Grid>
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can remove the tick? So when I click on it there is no tick but simply the color changes?

Comment: You can remove Path x:Name="optionMark" from markGrid and also remove all triggers setters where targetname is optionMark. Second option is to set opacity value to 0 for optionaMark in <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">